# Как я могу сравнить 2 изображения в ImageView, чтобы выполнить какое-то действие, если на экране изображен крот

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

У моём приложение есть 9 ImageView [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал чтобы через несколько секунд на экране появлялся крот[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на крота в счетчик шло значение +1.

есть 2 функции setBlackHole устанавливает все изображения черные, а setMoleImage рандомно показывает крота и при нажатии на него добавляет +1

```
    fun setBlackHole() {
    var listImage = mutableListOf(im1, im2, im3, im4, im5, im6, im7, im8, im9)
    if (isAdded() && activity != null) {
        for (i in listImage.indices) {
            var blackhole = listImage[i]
            blackhole.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hole1)
        }
    }
}

fun setMoleImage() {
    var listImage = mutableListOf(im1, im2, im3, im4, im5, im6, im7, im8, im9)
    val random = Random
    var setImageMoleRandom = listImage[random.nextInt(listImage.size)]
    if (isAdded() && activity != null) {
        setImageMoleRandom.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mole)
        for (i in listImage.indices){
            var setImage = listImage[i]
            setImage.setOnClickListener {
                if (setImage.drawable.constantState == APP_ACTIVITY.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mole).constantState){
                    txt_scrore_subtitle.text = score.toString()
                    score = score + 1
                    saveScore()
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "GO GO POWER RANGERS")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: непонятно в чем проблема. зачем сравнить изображения, ведь где находится крот и так известно

Comment: Вам не нужно искать крота - вы сами ему говорите где торчать. Просто запомните в какой он ячейке сейчас и в обработчике касания сравните в ту ли самую ячейку ткнул юзер.

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать сетку состояния поля в виде двумерного массива из `Boolean`  переменных, и одновременно изменяя состояния поля - перерисовывать нужные `ImageView`.

[Вот](https://gitlab.com/KrackensCorp/whac-a-mole-game) пример проекта где решается этот кейс похожим образом

Возможно не самое изящное решение, но очень наглядное

P.S. Кажется у кротов нет глаз...

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Лучше написать так в пустом топике чем просто не написать - из за того что забуду об этом когда наберу нужную репутацию.
Честно говоря, такое еще и побуждает писать ответы ради ответов чтобы собрать за или против.